# A Switch Java problem : case expressions must be constant expressions

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I having a problem in my switch/case statement. The error says : "Case expressions must be constant expressions". I understand the error and I can resolve it using If but can someone tells me why the case expression must be constant in a switch/case. 
A code example of my error :

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int idDirectory = ((MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.createDirectory)).getItemId();
    int idSuppression = ((MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.recycleTrash)).getItemId();
    int idSeeTrash = ((MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.seeTrash)).getItemId();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case idDirectory:
        createDirectory(currentDirectory);
        break;
    case idSuppression:
        recycleTrash();
        break;
    case idSeeTrash:
        seeTrash();
        break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Thx for your explanation !!

Comment: Why are you using `findViewById().getItemId()`? If you already have the id, you don't need to get the item in order to get the id!

Comment: switch statements are a bad smell... I recommend you look into using polymorphism or the adapter pattern in order to achieve better looking code. Additionally you can avoid problems like these altogether.

Comment: @Bnjmn I agree, specially when the condition repeats quite often. If you use it seldom it may be ok. Also, I use it sometimes with polymorphism to create the initial concrete instance.

Comment: @Bnjmn: Since Dimitri's using Android, his `MenuItem` objects are likely defined in xml and (to my knowledge) cannot be easily subclassed without abandoning the simplicity of `MenuInflater.inflate()`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

So it can be evaluated during the compilation phase ( statically check )

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11 for a formal definition of the `switch`.

Additionally it may help you to understand better how that `switch` is transformed into bytecode:

```
class Switch {
  void x(int n ) {
    switch( n ) {
      case 1: System.out.println("one"); break;
      case 9: System.out.println("nine"); break;
      default:  System.out.println("nothing"); break;
    }
  }
}
```

And after compiling:

```
C:\>javap -c Switch
Compiled from "Switch.java"
class Switch extends java.lang.Object{
Switch();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

void x(int);
  Code:
   0:   iload_1
   1:   lookupswitch{ //2
                1: 28;
                9: 39;
                default: 50 }
   28:  getstatic       #2; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   31:  ldc     #3; //String one
   33:  invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   36:  goto    58
   39:  getstatic       #2; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   42:  ldc     #5; //String nine
   44:  invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   47:  goto    58
   50:  getstatic       #2; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   53:  ldc     #6; //String nothing
   55:  invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   58:  return

}
```

See that line marked as `1:`

```
 1:   lookupswitch{ //2
            1: 28;
            9: 39;
            default: 50 }
```

It evaluates the value and goes to some other line. For instance if value is `9` it will jump to instruction 39:

```
   39:  getstatic       #2; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   42:  ldc     #5; //String nine
   44:  invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   47:  goto    58
```

Which in turn jumps to instruction 58 :

```
   58:  return
```

All this wouldn't be possible if it was evaluated dynamically.  That's why.

Comment: Thanks man, that's a nice answer. So if compile with javap, i can see the bytecode generated??

Comment: @Dimitri. You're welcome.  `javap` is another tool ( like javadoc or jar )  which is the default java dissambler. If invoked with `-c` you'll see these instructions.

Comment: Ok. But i was thinking, do you think the bytecode generated in the JVM is the same in Dalvik Machine (Android). I am working on Android as you may see it

Comment: Actually... it is not the same. Dalvik has its own codes, but the switch will work the same in both. Take a good look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)

Comment: Great answer to clearly understand the working of switch case. Worth Upvoting.

Answer (score 13):

in eclipse IDE is simple ,in switch sentence CTRL + 1 and convert switch sentence - if-else sentence http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields

Answer (score 3):

The `idDirectory` and others need to be a constant and not a declared variable. `Switch` will not work in this case, you need switch to `if-else` construct.

**EDIT** I see what OP meant. That is just how switch works in java language.

Comment: This is exactly your problem.  If you can't get around this with constants just use a slightly more complex if-then-else-if-blah-blah setup.

Comment: -1 For answering what the OP already knows: *I understand the error and I can resolve it using If but can someone tells me why the case expression must be constant in a switch/case*